# How to define marker color based on category string value for a 3d scatter plot

Tags: r, plot, scatter3d

I am going to plot a 3D scatter in R and I'd like to color the points in the plot based on the string or number category.

The category is

```
"cancer control control control control cancer  cancer  control cancer  control........"
```

or

```
1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0......
```

the code is as follows:

```
library("plot3D")
scatter3D(pcr$PC1, pcr$PC2, pcr$PC3,color=category)
```

The output is
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzNNx.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should upload a reproducible example, but i think that your `category` variable is continuous. you should change into a factor.

```
yourdata$category = as.factor(yourdata$category)
```

then you try to plot graph again.
maybe it will help you.

Comment: thanks so much for your response. no my color data are factor.